# Can I use a Dart interface from manually written JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, compilation, dart

I consider using Dart for my next web project and it has made a very neat impression on me so far. Obviously, Dart code can be converted into JavaScript. However, I wonder if this results in code where functions can be used from other JavaScript files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is supported to call Dart functions from JavaScript but only functions that are made available to JavaScript explicitely.

See

- [Calling Dart code from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23104432)
- [Expose Dart functions to javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15669163)

When you build Dart to JavaScript minification and tree-shaking make it hard or mostly impossible to call methods because functions might not even be included in the output if the analysis recognized that the function isn't called anywhere and if it actually is included it will have a shortened and cryptic name.

I have seen it mentioned that here are attempts for better support of this use case but there isn't anything available yet.

Answer (score 2):

If your generated JavaScript is accessible then for sure it will regardless of it is generated using dart or anything else

Comment: Only theoretically, see my answer.

Comment: Having cryptic names of function dose not mean they are not accessible, yes they are hard to use. Here concen is only whether they are accessible or not I guess

Comment: It is also not guaranteed that they get the same name with consecutive builds, so in practice I would say they can't be called, in theory they might (if they were not pruned by tree-shaking).

Comment: Yes, this is possible problem case