# Making a Dart function callable from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, flutter, web, dart-js-interop, flutter-module

**Making a Dart function callable from JavaScript**

I'm trying to integrate a flutter module into a PWA application. I would like to access one Dart function from PWA using JS after the flutter web build is taken for integration. Used the following official package to call JavaScript APIs from Dart code, or vice versa.

flutter package - https://pub.dev/packages/js#making-a-dart-function-callable-from-javascript

following is the sample JS used for accessing a sample dart function, here I'm loading the **main.dart.js** which generated with

```
flutter build web
```

from flutter module

```
<script src="./main.dart.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function callMethodFromFlutter() {
window.functionName();
}
</script>
```

but getting the following errors with window and without window object

```
window.functionName is not a function
functionName is not defined
```

Any idea what’s wrong here? or any other alternative way for communication between a flutter module and PWA just like platform channels used for android/iOS.

I have seen similar questions but no proper solution on StackOverflow.

Comment: Did you call `allowInterop`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call a Dart function from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23104432/how-to-call-a-dart-function-from-javascript)

Comment: @Ivo No. I want to access a flutter function after building from the main.dart.js file. yes, I have used allowInterop in the dart code.  Please find the sample below

```
 @JS()
library callable_function;

import 'package:js/js.dart';

/// Allows calling the assigned function from Dart as well.
@JS()
external void functionName();

void _someDartFunction() {
  print('Hello from Dart!');
}

void main() {
  _functionName = allowInterop(_someDartFunction);
  // JavaScript code may now call `functionName()` or `window.functionName()`.
}
```